# How to restrict user input to the integer 1 or 2 and not allow user to enter anything other than a integer in java?

Tags: java, integer

I'm having so much trouble with this. I have tried multiple things but it still gives me an error message and crashes. I want to loop it until the user enters 1 or 2.

```
System.out.println("Please choose if you want a singly-linked list or a doubly-linked list.");
System.out.println("1. Singly-Linked List");
System.out.println("2. Doubly-Linked List");
int listChoice = scan.nextInt();
//Restrict user input to an integer only; this is a test of the do while loop but it is not working :(
do {
    System.out.println( "Enter either 1 or 2:" );
    listChoice = scan.nextInt();
} while ( !scan.hasNextInt() );
```

It gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at Main.main(Main.java:35)
```

Comment: Use `next` instead of `nextInt` and add `try/catch` to handle `NumberFormatException `... (Obviously use `if` to check if it's 1 or 2)

Comment: @Idos thanks! why would I use an if statement? it doesn't loop like a while loop. I don't want it to stop asking the user to enter in 1 or 2.

Comment: I meant use an `if` _inside_ the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use `nextLine` instead of `nextInt`, and deal with the exception afterwards.

```
boolean accepted = false;
do {
    try {
        listChoice = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        if(listChoice > 3 || listChoice < 1) {
            System.out.println("Choice must be between 1 and 2!");
        } else {
            accepted = false;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid number!");
    }
} while(!accepted);
```

Comment: Thank u so much!!! I think that is a really great thought process. I want to think logically too, but I am only a beginner and I feel stupid. I believe accepted = true in the else statement. If I put it as false, it keeps looping over and over again for me. And I also believe that it is if(listChoice >=3 || listChoice < 1)

Comment: It also still gives me trouble when I enter in a letter. I changed it to catch (InputMismatchException e) but it still says I have an InputMismatchException error.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this with the Switch Case statement as well.

```
switch(listchoice)
{
    case 1:
    //Statment
    break;

    case 2:
    //statement
    break;

    default:
    System.out.println("Your error message");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the user can enter anything, you have to read in a line as a String:

```
String input = scan.nextLine();
```

Once you've done that, the test is easy:

```
input.matches("[12]")
```

All together:

```
String input = null;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter either 1 or 2:");
    input = scan.nextLine();
} while (!input.matches("[12]")); 

int listChoice = Integer.parseInt(input); // input is only either "1" or "2"
```

Comment: that's an interesting approach! i'll try it as well! thank u!